# Upload multiple files with Multer ? (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I just can't figured whats wrong why my codes below. I try to upload multiple files that given by a simple uploader (JADE):

```
 input#upload-gallery(type='file', multiple="multiple", name='picture')
```

and some javascript controller, to send data each time a user insert files to uploader

```
   $("#upload-gallery").on('change', function(){
        var files = $(this).get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                formData.append('pictures', file, file.name);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url          : '/upload/pictures',
                type         : 'POST',
                data         : formData,
                processData  : false,
                contentType  : false,
                success      : function (links) {

                }
            });
        }
    })
```

Here's the server part:

```
var multer          = require('multer');
var upload          = multer({dest: "./gallery"});
...
...
app.post('/upload/pictures', upload.any(), function(req, res, next){
      console.log(req.files)  // <-- it always return [] array
});
```

The problem is that `req.files` always return an empty array. I can make it to upload single file just fine, but I can't make it upload multiple files. So what's wrong here?

What I have tried so far:

- change `formData` part to `formData.append('pictures[]', file, file.name);` not working
- Change `upload.any()` to `upload.array('pcitures')`, doesn't work

Comment: I got it working for me with the code you had provided. Is there a conflicting route or form is not multipart/form-data?

Comment: You're right. I create another new clean project just to test whether I have malfunction `node` or something else. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have `multipart`plugin that is conflicting with `multer`. Just commented out these in app.js

```
//var multipart       = require('connect-multiparty');
//app.use(multipart());
```

and the problem's gone